# If I run the script from a command line (as root), it works. If it runs at a boot time, it fails

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, aws-cli

I have a shell script that I want to run at boot time. In this script I'm using aws cli to update my IP to route53 record set, if I run the script from a command line (as root user), it works. If it runs at a boot time, it fails. I configured aws credential for root user already.
My update-route53-record.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

DOMAIN_NAME="mydomain.com"
HOSTED_ZONE_ID="Z1986XXXXXXXXX"

main(){
    UPDATED_IP_LIST=$(updated_ip_list)    
    update_route53_record "$UPDATED_IP_LIST"
}

# Get IP List of $DOMAIN_NAME from route53
get_ip_list(){
    RECORD_SET_JSON=$( aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z1986QIYBBYSUJ --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Name == '$DOMAIN_NAME.']")

    #Remove the first and last character in string  to convert json array to json object
    RECORD_SET_JSON=${RECORD_SET_JSON:1:-1}

    # Need to install jq to parse json http://xmodulo.com/how-to-parse-json-string-via-command-line-on-linux.html
    # Get value of ResourceRecords
    RECORD_SET_JSON=$( echo $RECORD_SET_JSON | jq -r '.ResourceRecords' )

    echo $RECORD_SET_JSON
}

updated_ip_list(){
    # Get public IP of running instance
    IP=$( curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 )
    # IP="192.168.10.1"

    # Get IP list from Route53 by invoking get_ip_list
    IP_LIST=$(get_ip_list)    

    # Get length of json array
    LENGTH=$(echo $IP_LIST | jq '. | length')

    # Add one element to last array
    IP_LIST=$(echo $IP_LIST | jq '.['$LENGTH'].Value |= .+ '\"$IP\"'')

    echo $IP_LIST
}

update_route53_record(){   
    JSON_REQUEST='{
              "Comment": "Update the A record set",
              "Changes": [
                {
                  "Action": "UPSERT",
                  "ResourceRecordSet": {
                    "Name": '\"$DOMAIN_NAME\"',
                    "Type": "A",
                    "TTL": 300,
                    "ResourceRecords": '$1'
                  }
                }
              ]
            }'
    #echo $JSON_REQUEST
    #echo "Calling API..."
    aws route53 change-resource-record-sets  --hosted-zone-id "$HOSTED_ZONE_ID" --change-batch "$JSON_REQUEST"

    # write to log file
    echo "aws route53 change-resource-record-sets  --hosted-zone-id \"$HOSTED_ZONE_ID\" --change-batch \"$JSON_REQUEST\"" | sudo tee /var/log/update-route53.log
}
main
exit 0
```

I install my script runs at boot time

```
sudo cp update-route53-record.sh /etc/init.d
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/update-route53-record.sh
sudo update-rc.d update-route53-record.sh defaults 98 02
```

But if I run the script from a command line (as root), it works. If it runs at a boot time, it fails. I configured aws credential for root user already.
Could you please help?

Comment: the 169. range is usually an "unable to get IP" type address.  Would I be right is guessing you are attempting to run the script before the network card drivers are fully loaded?

Comment: @SteveMatthews So how to run the script at boot time but after the network card drivers are fully loaded?

Comment: You could perhaps add a sleep to the start of your script so it starts but then waits?

Comment: @SteveMatthews It was able to get IP. I can print out the IP when I'm debugging.

Answer (score 2):

This might be because you're using `sudo` in your userdata. AWS runs these commands as root, and using sudo won't work because sudo requires a tty.

From the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts):

> Scripts entered as user data are executed as the root user, so do not use the sudo command in the script.

Try removing sudo and see how you go.